Workbooks.Open does not find file even though it resides in the directory
I can't get the code to find and open the file at an http address, even though I have access to it and I can see the file in the folder and can manually open it.
MY CODE:
Sheets("Control").Select
    ZuluAdj = Range("b8").Value
    ResetFlag = Range("h7").Value
    LastCol = Range("b10").Value
    ThisFile = Range("b4").Value
    CSAFile = Range("b5").Value
    FilePath = Range("b6").Value    '\\20.4.0.200\users\CSAExports\
    
    If UCase(Range("b1").Value) = "Y" Then FilePath = "C:\Users\hk\OneDrive - xxx\Documents\"
    
    Set wb = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & CSAFile)
    
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then   'schedule file found
        errorspot = ""
        Range("a1").Select AND SO ON

When I run this code using the http address path, I get a "MS Excel cannot access the file" error. But when I use my C:\Users path, the code works just fine.
Any thoughts / suggestions?  I checked the related posts on this topic and could not resolve my issue through them. One of them suggested there were quotes around the file path, but I do not have that.

I just also tested this with "Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & FilePath), and the directory opened up just fine, with the file showing there.

Uhm, never mind . . . it appears that with that address I have to include the file extension, in this case ".csv".  Curiously, with the C: drive path I did not have to.

I'm surprised that the local path worked without the full file name.

FYI "\20.4.0.200\users\CSAExports" is a network/UNC path - that's not the same thing as an HTTP path

@JNevill - me too, but it seems like Excel will try to open any file with that name which has an extension it "knows" it can open.   You get a message eg "Could not find C:\Temp\Test.xlsx" if you call Workbooks.open("C:\Temp\Test") if there are no matching files.
